# Cant full read querystring data in mvc4 application using a class array as input to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made a mvc4 application and I have a Controller that outputs a png file like this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Foobar.Classes;

namespace Foobar.Controllers
{
  public class ImageController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index(Label[] labels)
    {
      var bmp = new Bitmap(400, 300);
      var pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
      var font = new Font("arial", 20);

      var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

      g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
      g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

      if (labels != null)
      {
        g.DrawString("" + labels.Length, font, pen.Brush, 20, 20);

        if (labels.Length > 0)
        {
          g.DrawString("" + labels[0].label, font, pen.Brush, 20, 40);
        }
      }

      var stream = new MemoryStream();
      bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

      stream.Position = 0;

      return File(stream, "image/png");
    }
  }
}
```

The Label class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Foobar.Classes
{
  public class Label
  {
    public string label { get; set; }
    public int fontsize { get; set; }
  }
}
```

When I run my controller having this in the url:

```
http://localhost:57775/image?labels[0][label]=Text+rad+1&labels[0][fontsize]=5&labels[1][fontsize]=5&labels[2][fontsize]=5
```

I get the correct amount of labels, so the image will show 3.
But the instances of Label will not get its data members fill in.
I have also tried to do this using plain variables (not properties).

If they were filled in, the image would actually show "3" and "Text rad 1".

So what do I put in the class "Label" to have the properties right? Should there be some kind of annotation?

Where do I read about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the querystring was wrong, should be this:

```
http://localhost:57775/image?labels[0].label=Text+rad+1&labels[0].fontsize=5&labels[1].fontsize=5&labels[2].fontsize=5
```